# iCarousel show view on tap

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

So I have a carousel set up with 9 items and a different gradient for each.
I want to be able to tap on an item and show it has been selected by greying it out or applying a view on top with a tick.

The problem is, I am not sure how to apply the view to only the item that has been tapped as the didSelectItemAt and viewForItemAt functions are separate.

TLDR: I'm trying to make it so I can show an item on the carousel has been selected by applying a view on top of the item.

My code:

```
// Configure slides
var carouselSlides = ["1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

// Set gradient colours
var gradientColours = [

// 0 1
    UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.76, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:0.11, alpha:1.0),
// 2 3
    UIColor(red:0.38, green:0.02, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.67, green:0.03, blue:0.42, alpha:1.0),
// 4 5
    UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.12, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.23, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0),
// 6 7
    UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.75, blue:0.99, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.19, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0),
// 8 9
    UIColor(red:0.28, green:0.33, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.20, blue:0.24, alpha:1.0),
// 10 11
    UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.30, blue:0.24, alpha:1.0),
// 12 13
    UIColor(red:0.38, green:0.42, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.30, blue:0.42, alpha:1.0),
// 14 15
    UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.17, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.80, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0),
// 16 17
    UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.32, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.87, green:0.14, blue:0.46, alpha:1.0)]


let indexOfGradientColor = 0
var slideIndex = 0

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // Carousel configuration
    carouselView.type = .coverFlow
    carouselView.scrollToItem(at: carouselSlides.count / 2, animated: false)

    // Gradient background
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    //Set colours
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:0.03, green:0.14, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0).cgColor,
        UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.04, blue:0.15, alpha:1.0).cgColor]

    gradientBackground.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    let viewSizeHeight = 160
    let viewSizeWidth = 275

    let frontView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewSizeWidth, height: viewSizeHeight))
    frontView.contentMode = .center
    frontView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    frontView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = frontView.bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    if index == 0 {
        //1
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[12].cgColor, gradientColours[13].cgColor]
    } else if index == 1 {
        //2
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[10].cgColor, gradientColours[11].cgColor]
    } else if index == 2 {
        //3
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[14].cgColor, gradientColours[15].cgColor]
    } else if index == 3 {
        //4
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[4].cgColor, gradientColours[5].cgColor]
    } else if index == 4 {
        //5
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[0].cgColor, gradientColours[1].cgColor]
    } else if index == 5 {
        //7
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[6].cgColor, gradientColours[7].cgColor]
    } else if index == 6 {
        //8
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[8].cgColor, gradientColours[9].cgColor]
    } else if index == 7 {
        //9
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[2].cgColor, gradientColours[3].cgColor]
    } else if index == 8 {
        //10
        gradient.colors = [gradientColours[16].cgColor, gradientColours[17].cgColor]
    }

    frontView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)


    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: -55, width: viewSizeWidth, height: viewSizeHeight))
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 4
    frontView.addSubview(titleLabel)


    titleLabel.text = "\(carouselSlides[index])"

    return frontView
}

func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return carouselSlides.count
}


func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    switch (option) {

    case .spacing:
        return value * 1.05

    case .count:
        return CGFloat(carouselSlides.count)

    default:
        return value;

    }
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {

    switch index {
    case 0:

        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stored selected Index into one array as its been selected. And you need to put check in viewAtIndex method for same.

Take an array object to hold index value:

```
var arrySelectedIndex = NSMutableArray()
```

Replace below method:

```
  func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
    {
        let viewSizeHeight = 160
        let viewSizeWidth = 275

        let frontView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewSizeWidth, height: viewSizeHeight))
        frontView.contentMode = .center
        frontView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
        frontView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = frontView.bounds
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        if arrySelectedIndex.contains(index)
        {
            // Index is selected so put your custom colog
            gradient.colors = GIVE_YOUR_OWN_COLOR_TO_SEPERATE
        }
        else
        {

            // Index is not selected so go with normal
            if index == 0 {
                //1
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[12].cgColor, gradientColours[13].cgColor]
            } else if index == 1 {
                //2
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[10].cgColor, gradientColours[11].cgColor]
            } else if index == 2 {
                //3
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[14].cgColor, gradientColours[15].cgColor]
            } else if index == 3 {
                //4
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[4].cgColor, gradientColours[5].cgColor]
            } else if index == 4 {
                //5
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[0].cgColor, gradientColours[1].cgColor]
            } else if index == 5 {
                //7
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[6].cgColor, gradientColours[7].cgColor]
            } else if index == 6 {
                //8
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[8].cgColor, gradientColours[9].cgColor]
            } else if index == 7 {
                //9
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[2].cgColor, gradientColours[3].cgColor]
            } else if index == 8 {
                //10
                gradient.colors = [gradientColours[16].cgColor, gradientColours[17].cgColor]
            }
        }
        frontView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)


        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: -55, width: viewSizeWidth, height: viewSizeHeight))
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 4
        frontView.addSubview(titleLabel)


        titleLabel.text = "\(carouselSlides[index])"

        return frontView
    }


    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {

          if arrySelectedIndex.contains(index)
            {
                arrySelectedIndex.remove(index)
            }
            else
            {
                arrySelectedIndex.add(index);
            }
           carousel.reloadData()
    }
```